# ConcurrentLinkedQueue poll() producing corrupt data?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I am currently working on a Java project which process raw packets as they cross the wire.  Data is read in by libpcap, and then each packet is put into a byte[] and then put into a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, which a thread reads and processes data from.

```
    static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte[]> packetQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<byte[]>();

    public void nextPacket(PcapHeader header, ByteBuffer buffer PcapDumper user) {
        pcapBufferCapacity = buffer.capacity();

        if (pcapBufferCapacity > 54) {
            dumper.dump(header, buffer);
        }

        if (pcapBufferCapacity > 43) {
            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(packetBytes);
            packetQueue.add(packetBytes); // Data being added to the queue  
        }
    }
```

I then have a thread which is running...

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Parser()); // Parser extends Runnable
```

...that poll()'s the queue for work and then processes the data.

```
int parserByteCount;
byte[] packetBytes;

public void run() {
    packetBytes = MyClass.packetQueue.poll();
    parserByteCount = packetBytes.length;
    doStuff();
}
```

Everything works as expected when I run one Parser() thread.  However, if I run more than one parser thread...

```
Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Parser());
```

...the data coming from MyClass.packetQueue.poll() becomes corrupt and my results are inconsistent while reading from a static PCAP file.  Considering it works flawlessly with one Parser() thread but becomes corrupt when multiple Parser() threads are running, I presume this has something to do with concurrency.  However, as the data is put/poll-ed from a ConcurrentLinkedQueue, shouldn't it work correctly between threads?  What am I missing?

Thank you for any insight you have.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "the data coming ... becomes corrupt.." ?

Comment: This is a great example of a problem that you would probably solve yourself simply by trying to create a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that we could run.  By going through the error yourself in order to create a demo, you'll probably find exactly what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int parserByteCount;
byte[] packetBytes;
```

Are these member variables of your `Parser` class? Are they required for correct parsing inside `doStuff()`?

If you answered *yes* two times, you may be in trouble. Remember that threads share memory. Therefore access to all instance or class level variables, that may be accessed concurrently, **must** be synchronized. Note that local variables are not shared - they live on the stack, which is unique for each thread. An easy fix would be to change the two critical variables into local variables, passing them around as method arguments if necessary.

Comment: This was the issue.  Thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

> ConcurrentLinkedQueue poll() producing corrupt data?

If this is implying that the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is at fault then that is extremely unlikely.  I suspect it is either how you are putting the data into the queue or how you are consuming it.

```
byte[] packetBytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(packetBytes);
packetQueue.add(packetBytes); // Data being added to the queue
```

This code looks fine.  I was worried that you were re-using a `byte[]` but I see no problems here.

```
packetBytes = MyClass.packetQueue.poll();
parserByteCount = packetBytes.length;
doStuff();
```

This looks fine except the `poll()` might return `null` that you should check for.   You might consider switching to the `LinkedBlockingQueue` which allows more methods around waiting for entries in the queue.  But that's not going to fix your problem.

That leaves some problem in `doStuff()`.

- Is `doStuff()` updating some common object which is not being `synchronized`?  Maybe an output file or some other persistance mechanism?
- Should you be passing in `packetBytes` to `doStuff()` instead of making it an instance variable?
- Is any part of your processing modifying the `packetBytes` array inappropriately?  Not sure why this would work with one thread but not two though.

> the data coming from MyClass.packetQueue.poll() becomes corrupt and my results are inconsistent

Can you be more explicit about the "corrupt"?  Can you do a `System.out.println(...)` and dump the values in the array when they are added to the queue and when they are removed?  I think you will see that the queue is not the issue.